# How To Setup ostree and rpm-ostree on openEuler？

Tags: linux, fedora, updates, yum, rpm

I have a task which is to test the rpm-ostree on openEuler. It seems not set up correctly, simply installing it with yum may not enable it.

```
> rpm-ostree status
error: This system was not booted via libostree; cannot operate`
```

I have read the documentation of both ostree and rpm-ostree, but can not find out how to set it up.

As far as I know, some OS support this feature, such as CoreOS. Is it only running on the particular configured OS?

Is there any way to set it up on the other Linux-based system?